# Joining two tables without duplicates

Tags: mysql, database

I just recently posted an issue I was having with Mysql, turns out it was a problem on my part, I forgot to add a field. Now that this query is working:

```
SELECT e.*, b.item_count FROM inventory e, inventory2 b 
WHERE (e.sku_id = b.parent_id AND b.item_count > 0) 
AND (e.item_name LIKE '%Cherry%' OR e.item_artist_name LIKE '%Cherry%' 
OR e.item_description LIKE '%Cherry%' OR e.item_media LIKE '%Cherry%' 
OR e.item_genre LIKE '%Cherry%' OR e.item_tags LIKE '%Cherry%')
```

This works perfectly, however I do not want it to duplicate the results,
right now I currently get the following results:

```
+--------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| sku_id |          item_name          | item_description |
+--------+-----------------------------+------------------+
|      1 | Cherry Blossoms             | Description      |
|      1 | Cherry Blossoms Description | Description      |
|     46 | Wild Cherry                 | Description      |
|     46 | Wild Cherry                 | Description      |
|      1 | Cherry Blossoms Description | Description      |
+--------+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

I want the following output however:

```
 +--------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
 | sku_id |          item_name          | item_description  |  
 +--------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
 |      1 | Cherry Blossoms             | Description       |
 |     46 | Wild Cherry                 | Description       |
 +--------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: maybe just join them, and then remove the duplicates? search for "SQL remove duplicates" on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group by id like:

```
 ...myQuery
 GROUP BY e.sku_id
```

Note: Implicit joins are discouraged and you should use explicit joins like `TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON ...`

Comment: Thank you! GROUP BY worked, and I will use INNER JOIN thank you.

Comment: Make sure you click on tick below vote count so this answer would help others in future.

Answer (score -1):

you need a aggregate function to use a group by function so use aggregrate function and use group by clause.